# Android: Change imageview src in included xml

Tags: android, xml, include, imageview

Is it possible to change an imageView src in an included xml from another xml?

In included several images for a menu bar with the following include:

```
        <include layout="@layout/panel_settings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top">
        </include>
```

The include looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_icon_panel_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_relativelayout_settings_menu_bar_right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout_titel_panel"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/RelativeLayout_Settings_CenterPanel"
    android:layout_weight="0.86"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_settings_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/settings" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_settings_contra_con"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/contracon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_settings_error_log"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/errorlog" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_settings_reconnect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/screen" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_settings_invis"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/autostart"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to change the  android:src tag via the the top xml which includes. How is that possible?

Comment: why don't you change it programmatically?

Comment: Good question, I hesitated because I thought i could be possible via xml.

Comment: so just use yourimageview.setImageresource(R.drawable.youricon);

Answer (score -1):

You can  assign an id for the *include widget* and then access the *include widget* in the code.
[image]

---

Once you can access the *include widget*, you can access all the elements inside the included layout file.
[image]

---

---

NOTE : I've used dataBinding
[image]

You can also do this without using the data binding. Just like the legacy method

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sending code as texts is always recommended.